# How do you open a link in a new window within a JavaScript String?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to open a link in a new window in a JavaScript String

I want to change the text of an element and I am calling a function to do that.

```
 changeText("Text text text <a href=http://somewebsite?target=_blank>ext</a>.texttexttext ");

function changeText(textChange){
//Change text code
}
```

This doesn't open a new window it just opens the link.

Comment: I'm not fully clear on what you're asking for. Are you just looking for the `window.open` function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DOMParser API to parse a string into DOM that you can use pure JavaScript methods to query/manipulate. Something like this:

```
changeText("Text text text <a href=http://somewebsite?ext</a>.texttexttext ");

function changeText(textChange){
    var domparser = new DOMParser();
    var domsnippet = domparser.parseFromString(textChange,"text/html");
    var links = domsnippet.querySelectorAll("a");
    console.log(links);
    window.open(links[0]["href"],"_blank", 'width=200,height=400')
}
```